# Use "find" to list all c/h/cc files but exclude symlinks

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

I am trying to get a listing of the `c/h/cc` files in a directory, but I want the file `symlink` to be excluded.

I used the following command to list the files, which works fine.

```
find . -name *.c -o -name *.h -o  -name *.cc
```

I tried adding the option  `-type f` to prune the listing of file symlink, but no luck.  Basically I want to find to give me listing of (.c or .h or .cc files) and file type `regular file`.

My goal is to save the list of files into `cscope.files` and run `cscope` on it, and currently cscope complains about `symlinks`.

Thank you.

Comment: I figured out one way to get the proper listing (thought not too elegant):  find . -type f  | egrep "\.c$|\.h$|\.cc$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely works for me. Are you sure your shell isn't expanding the * in your commandline? Or you didn't apply -type f to all your items:

```
find . -type f -and \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o  -name "*.cc" \)
```

Comment: Cool, escaping the parenthesis is what I was missing.  Thank you.  Your solution is better than what I posted earlier, and more efficient (time wise).